# Spring Boot: Externalized configuration in file

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-boot, configuration-files

I am building a webapplication using Spring Boot, and wish to externalize my configuration. I wish to do this for both my `spring.datasource.*` information, and other information, which I can apparently inject using `@Value("${name}")`, for example.

I was wondering where I can actually place this file during development (on a Windows machine), and for production (on a Linux machine), in a way that keeps sensitive information out of my code versioning system.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a application.properties aside to the fat-jar, so you don't need to provide the sensitive properties at buildtime and keep them out of your VCS.

Have a look at boots [reference guide - externalized configuration section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for your several options. And this section for [location-order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).